# Reactive output inside tabPanel using user input

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, subset, reactive

I am trying to create an application which filters data by first choosing a subset of data which produced in a separate script **do_data.R** and then filters this subset by several indicators selected by users.

My reproduced example is shown below:

My **ui.R** file is:

```
source("do_label.R")

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("lumen"),
fluidRow(
column(width = 8, includeMarkdown("intro_data.md")),
column(width = 4, includeHTML("intro_logo.html"))
), 
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("indicator", "Indicator:", choices = indicator),
  selectInput("category", "Category:", choices = category)
  sliderInput("year", "Year:", min = 2011, max = 2016, value = 1, sep = "")
),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel('Data',    DT::dataTableOutput('ex1')),
tabPanel('Graphs',      DT::dataTableOutput('ex2'))
)
))
))
```

and my **server.R** file is:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

source("do_data.R")

# Load the dataset
loadData <- function() {
df <- surveydata
return(df)
}

getTable <- function(df, reaction){

if(input$indicator == "df1")
return(df1)
else
return(df1)  
}


##### GLOBAL OBJECTS #####

# Shared data
globalData <- loadData()

##### SHINY SERVER #####
# Create shiny server.
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
cat("Press \"ESC\" to exit...\n")
# Copy the data frame 
localFrame <- globalData


getReaction4 <- reactive({
return(list(indicator = input$indicator
))
}) # getReaction4 
# Output table.
output$table = DT::renderDataTable({print(getTable(localFrame,   getReaction4()))} # output table
```

})

My problem is that my subsets **df1** and **df2** are not shown at all and **sidebarPanel** seems to be completely not functional. Can you help please by some basic advice on what I missing here?

Regards

Comment: Sorry, had a look, but there is just too little to go on. At least 4 source files missing, variables undefined, no data, etc.. Most of the program is missing. Try creating a small example that does what you want, and build up from there. Also there are syntactical errors in what actually is posted. This will not compile.

Comment: Thx Mike. You are right cannot put all in here. I have a do_data.R file where dataframes are produced and a do_label.R file where I fetch indicator year and category as vectors. The other 2 source files are just UI without any core functionality. Anyway I just need some mini example where dataframe subsetted and filtered by user input in sidepanel  can show results in some tab without mixing with functionality of other tabs.